# Operation is not supported on this platform. Using EmbeddedFileProvider

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I already update all my nugets. When I build it in debug mode there is no problem.
Is there a workaround for this or even a proper solution?

Here is my startup method where i load the appsettings with the embedfileprovider for the configurationbuilder.

```
        public AppStartup(
            Action<IConfigurationBuilder> platformConfiguration,
            Action<ILoggingBuilder, IConfigurationRoot> logging)
        {
            IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile(new EmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(AppStartup).Assembly, typeof(AppStartup).Namespace), "appsettings.json", false, false);

#if DEBUG
            builder.AddJsonFile(
                new EmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(AppStartup).Assembly, typeof(AppStartup).Namespace), "appsettings.development.json", true, false);
#endif

            platformConfiguration?.Invoke(builder); 

            _configuration = builder.Build(); // <= error thrown here
            _logging = logging;
        }
```

I get follow error when i try to run my Xamarin UWP app in release mode:

```
   at System.Func`2.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result) in f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.CoreLib\shared\System\Runtime\Intrinsics\X86\Sse41.PlatformNotSupported.cs:line 551
   at System.Reflection.Runtime.Assemblies.NativeFormat.NativeFormatRuntimeAssembly.GetManifestResourceInfo(String resourceName) in f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Reflection.Core\src\System\Reflection\Runtime\Assemblies\NativeFormat\NativeFormatRuntimeAssembly.cs:line 153
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.EmbeddedFileProvider.GetFileInfo(String subpath)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at MYNAMESPACE.AppStartup..ctor(Action`1 platformConfiguration, Action`2 logging) in MYFILEPATH\AppStartup.cs:line 38
   at MYNAMESPACE.UWP.App..ctor() in MYFILEPATH\App.xaml.cs:line 22
   at MYNAMESPACE.UWP.Program.<>c.<Main>b__0_0(ApplicationInitializationCallbackParams p) in MYFILEPATH\obj\x86\Release\App.g.i.cs:line 24
   at System.Func`2.Invoke(T arg)
   at __Interop.ReverseComStubs.Stub_5[TArg0](Object __this, Void* unsafe_e, IntPtr __methodPtr)
```

UWP csproj nugets:

```xml
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics">
        <Version>4.4.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="MonkeyCache.FileStore">
        <Version>1.5.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog">
        <Version>2.10.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sink.AppCenter">
        <Version>1.3.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console">
        <Version>4.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File">
        <Version>5.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Trace">
        <Version>3.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Shiny">
        <Version>2.3.0.2906</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Shiny.BluetoothLE">
        <Version>2.3.0.2906</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Shiny.Core">
        <Version>2.3.0.2906</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="5.0.0.2196" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform" Version="6.2.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.7.0" />
```

shared app csproj nugets:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics" Version="4.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sink.AppCenter" Version="1.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Shiny" Version="2.3.0.2906" />
    <PackageReference Include="Shiny.BluetoothLE" Version="2.3.0.2906" />
    <PackageReference Include="Shiny.Core" Version="2.3.0.2906" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.CommunityToolkit" Version="1.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="5.0.0.2196" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.7.0" />
```

My Environment:

```
    .NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
    Version:   6.0.100-rc.2.21505.57
    Commit:    ab39070116

    Runtime Environment:
    OS Name:     Windows
    OS Version:  10.0.22000
    OS Platform: Windows
    RID:         win10-x64
    Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100-rc.2.21505.57\

    Host (useful for support):
    Version: 6.0.0-rc.2.21480.5
    Commit:  6b11d64e7e

    .NET SDKs installed:
    5.0.302 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
    6.0.100-rc.2.21505.57 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

    .NET runtimes installed:
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.0-rc.2.21480.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
    Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
    Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
    Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.0-rc.2.21480.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
    Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
    Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
    Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.0-rc.2.21501.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

**temporary workaround**

```
builder
    .SetBasePath(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.uwp.json", optional: false);
```

**Update**
I update all the nugets to the latest .net 6 version and also xamarin to version 5.

Comment: If you "Run without debugging" the debug build, does that work, or show the same problem? I believe `Sse41.PlatformNotSupported` means the JIT'd native code attempts to use an SSE4.1 SIMD cpu instruction on a chip that lacks that instruction. But `NativeFormatRuntimeAssembly.cs` should have been written to work on any chip. This appears to be a bug either in how unsafe code was written in NativeFormatRuntimeAssembly, OR a bug in JIT compiler. You would have to submit an issue (I'm not sure where), and hope that an expert in one of those technologies suggests a work-around, or a patch fix. :(

Comment: An alternative possibility is that the error message is misleading, and its something else about Release packaging. To isolate what, make a third Build Configuration. Start with a clone of Debug Configuration, and change settings to be like Release. One setting at a time, till it breaks. Then google exceptions related to that setting.

Comment: Above code could run without exception in my side. could you share more detail about your run device and OS version?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT i update my question with more infos

Comment: It's hard to detect the problem, it looks you have found the workaround  for this problem, you could post it as answer. and if you do want fix this, please feel free post problem report in  runtime [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime) box.